# How to scroll using appium in Python

Tags: python, automation, scroll, appium

Hi I want to know how to scroll in appium using python

I have done it in Java before and it worked really well.

```
driver.scrollTo("Destination");
```

However I can't seem to do the same in python. I am fairly new to python and I have try doing multiple ways to scroll

One way I tried was

```
el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_name('Starting')
el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_name('Ending')
self.driver.scroll(el1, el2)
```

second way I tried was

```
self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("DesinationText").instance(0));').
```

second way scroll once but didn't scroll all the way down so it threw NoSuchElementException. 
Also, can someone explain to me what instances are in UiSelector?
I read the description but I didn't quite understand

Instance: Set the search criteria to match the widget by its instance number.

Comment: @Ganwk , your UI automator query should have any one of scrollview like listview , gridview or recyclerview. Please check this video which latets appium 1.5.3 version commands:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Answer (score 5):

`self.driver.scroll(el1, el2)` is not working for me either.

I started using

```
self.driver.swipe(470, 1400, 470, 1000, 400)
```

`driver.swipe(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, duration)` will be available in _touch.py file

Swipe down slowly, add a logic to check if the element is present - continue till the element is found.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using coordinate even though its not the best solution it works for me at the moment

```
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
el = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, loc)))
action.press(el).move_to(x=10, y=-500).release().perform()
```

Comment: is the negative value working for you?Coz when give a negative y axis i get `The coordinates provided to an interactions operation are invalid.`

Answer (score -1):

instance(i) is like index(i) but for some reason works better.

what is it used for?
let's say that in the current activity we are testing (which is present on the screen), there are 10 TextView views.
in that case the following selector:

> new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView")

is a good match for all of the 10 TextView views we have on the screen, but if you don't specify exactly which instance\index you want to match, it will return the first one by default.
But, let's assume you want to have a match specifically for the 10th TextView, just use the following selector:

> new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").instance(10)

The code you have written is good and is working. i have wrapped it up with example of how to handle errors:

```
def scroll_to_text(text):
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator(
        'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("'+text+'").instance(0));')
    return element
except NoSuchElementException:
    logger.error('it was not found')
    return None
except Exception, e:
    logger.error("Unexpected error:")
    logger.exception(e)
    return None
```

So I guess you have a different problem than what you thought originally.
Please note:

1. new UiSelector().text("DesinationText") will try to match an element
   that will have the exact text "DesinationText". if it is contained
   in a larger text it won't be matched.
2. 'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)' in your code
   assumes that there is only one scrollable element in the current
   screen. maybe you have two listviews and the text is in another
   listview or any other scrollable item?

Hope this helps.
Gil.